# recaptcha v2 through error, no property found

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm using Laravel 10 with Livewire
and I got this error after implementing the recaptcha v2.

```
ERR_ABORTED 400
```

&

```
No property found for validation: [g-recaptcha-response]
```

Also the key and secret is added to env and services.php files.

please advice
Controller file

```
public $g_recaptcha_response;
.
.
.
public $rules = [
        'name' => ["max:250"],
        'g_recaptcha_response' => 'required|recaptcha'

    ];
```

AppServiceProvider file

```
public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('recaptcha', 'App\\Validators\\ReCaptcha@validate');

        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
```

View

```
<div wire:ignore>
@if(config('services.recaptcha.key'))
    <div class="g-recaptcha"
        data-sitekey="{{config('services.recaptcha.key')}}">
    </div>
    @endif
</div>
```

app/Validators/ReCaptcha.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Validators;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
class ReCaptcha
{
    public function validate($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
    {
        $client = new Client;
        $response = $client->post(
            'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
            [
                'form_params' =>
                    [
                        'secret' => config('services.recaptcha.secret'),
                        'response' => $value
                    ]
            ]
        );
        $body = json_decode((string)$response->getBody());
        return $body->success;
    }
}
```